# Android, Retrofit 2 POST request

Tags: android, post

I'm new to Android developing and I don't know how to do this, I've searched on the internet, but everything I've tried so far doesn't work. What I'm trying to do, is to send string to the server and the key must be "interval=". This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. I'm getting string time2 from spinner, but for now it doesn't matter, because I know that the spinner part works and POST doesn't.

```
 PostInterface service = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);
    service.postTime(time2);
```

and interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST
Call<Response> postTime(@Field("interval=") String time);
```

What I'm supposed to do net and how can I test it with http://requestb.in/ (never used it before, I just saw it can be used for POST testing)?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use retrofit in the first place ?
It's a good library, but if you're new to Android, i suggest to start with HttpClient.

In your sample, the execute method was not called.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("http://requestb.in/")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
PostInterface service = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);
Call<Response> call = service.postTime(time2);
call.execute()
```

In your interface (replace xxx by the token given by requestbin)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("xxxxxxx")
Call<Response> postTime(@Field("interval=") String time);
```

ps: Be aware that you should not launch any http calls on the main thread.

Comment: And, i'm not sure if you want to user "interval=" or "interval" as the key. but i recommend to remove the = from your key, @Field("interval")

Comment: My friend recommended retrofit to me, I used it for GET because I've found tutorial and it worked, so I tried to use it for POST as well. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I'm getting "Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException" on call.execute(), how to fix it?

Comment: What is the message of the exception ?

Comment: i'm getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, how to fix that?

Comment: @mustangws
it's because you execute a network request on the ui thread 
this normally happens when you try to call an API or some heavy weight code on the ui thread , these kind of requests should be done asynchronously u can use AsyncTasks or similar threading technique 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are posting a form field, you should remove the "=" from "interval="
fields are key and values, no need for the "="
if you want a test client for posts and get you can try [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

please clarify your question more if this is not what you expected as an answer

---

as @Mickael Monsang Answer
dont' use call.execute directly better use

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {}}
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried without "=" and it still doesn't work. To clarify the question: I have activity with two textviews, spiiner and button. First textview says "Choose interval" and to the right of it there's spinner (you can choose between 15min,30min,1h,2h and 3h). Then, when you choose interval you want, on button click chosen interval should be send to the server(so if you chose 15min on the server there should be displayed 15,in string time2 there only 15,without min). The other textview says "You chose xxmin interval.